# How do you view the customer connections who use your app with Quickbooks? Report?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How do you view your customer connections in the developer area?

Also, how do you switch the name for whom the app was created by? Right now it says Program Name by Individual - My name? Shouldnt it say Program Name by Company Name?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log into developer.intuit.com and click on the application, there is tab for reports. From there you can view the customer connections, including disconnecting them if needed.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0050_managing_your_app/connection_report

If you update your profile and change your company name it will be reflected on your application.

Thanks,
Jarred